# Android ImageViews upon eacht other / fade in fade out

Tags: android, animation, alpha

I've got two ImageViews and I try to fade out one and fade in another.

The Problem is they should "lay" upon each other.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="124dp"
android:layout_height="94dp"
android:src="@drawable/dgreen"
android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="124dp"
android:layout_height="94dp"
android:src="@drawable/blank" />
</RelativeLayout>

Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_out );
animation.setFillAfter(true);
Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_in );
animation1.setFillAfter(true);
iV.startAnimation(animation);

iV1.startAnimation(animation1);
```

But the picture below the first imageview does not "glow" through.

Edit: 
Here is my Fade in/out code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
android:duration="1000" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="0.1" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="1000" />
```

I use alpha transformation.

Comment: What's the code of the fade_in and fade out animations? Are you using alpha animation to make them transparent?

Comment: yes I use alpha animation to make one picture transparent and the other picture from transparent to opaque

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Framelayout and play with gravity like [here](http://slife.io/Mi0) and apply a Animation like [here](http://slife.io/MWg)